# Loading a Static File Within Injected HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to load a static file that is inside of injected html in my Django project:

```
<div class="bottom-box" id="left">
        <span id="title">Banks and cards</span>
        {{ card_info |safe}}
</div>
```

And here is the code that is being injected through the `card_info` variable:

```
"""
<p id="pay-card">
    <img id="pay-box-img" src="{%% static 'img/payment-card.png' %%}" height="14">
    <span id="card-number">%s x-%i %s</span>
</p>
"""
```

The issue line is: `src="{%% static 'img/payment-card.png' %%}"`.

When I inspect the HTML page, I see this line:

`src="{% static 'img/payment-card.png' %}"`

This is the line I am trying to get (taken from working static file):

`src="/static/img/payment-card.png"`

It seems to not be rending and I haven't the slightest clue as to how to get a static file link, inside of a variable, to render.

**Edit**

<del>Something else I have just noticed, my CSS does not seem to apply to the html code once it is loaded...</del> Issue has been resolved.

To clarify the above issue stated; I am testing in Safari and the previous CSS was continually being loaded instead of the new CSS I had written so I had to clear my cookies before I was able to use the new CSS...

**Resolution**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% for i in payment_info %}
<form class="card_display" method="post" action="/summary/default_swap/">
{% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <img id="pay-box-img" src="/static/img/payment-card.png" height="14">
        <input type="hidden" name="card-number" value="{{ i.last_4 }}"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
        <span id="card-number">{{ i.card_type }} x-{{ i.last_4 }} {{i.get_default_display }}</span>
    </p>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

The above code has done me the justice I need. The answer I accepted led me to this revelation. The above is done by, as stated by @Kyle, passing in the queryset and just iterating over it straight within the HTML in order to get the desired results I needed...

Comment: Why are you passing *1)* raw html to a template and *2)* python formatter markers that don't mean anything in HTML? You should probably explain why you provide that input and what you expect as output.

Comment: @Melvyn , the reason I am passing raw html is because I am rendering a list of card numbers that are pulled from a database object. I want to keep this in my python function and not do this locally in the HTML page. I get the expected output I desire, except for the fact that my static file does not load...

Comment: You do not understand your execution stack properly. Review the Django tutorial and go through it in order. What you call a "HTML page" is not a HTML page. It is a template *executed by python* which happens to have the file extension ".html".

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will retrace my steps and see what I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a specific reason why you are passing in the templated card_info via a context variable, but you should probably use the [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include) that is provided with Django.  The cool part about the include tag is that all included templates will get the same context that is used when you render the template.

**my_template.html**

```
<div class="bottom-box" id="left">
    <span id="title">Banks and cards</span>
    {% include "card_info.html" %}
</div>
```

**card_info.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<p id="pay-card">
    <img id="pay-box-img" src="{% static 'img/payment-card.png' %}" height="14">
    <span id="card-number">%s x-%i %s</span>
</p>
```

Comment: If I chose this method, how would I be able to populate `card_info.html` with my function that pulls card info from the database?

Comment: @M.Gilbert, when you "include" templates like we are in the above example; the same context gets passed into the "card_info.html" template.  So for example, if you render the my_template.html template with a variable called card_number, the template will pass that into your included template as well.

Comment: Ahh... Interesting. I am going to give this a try

Comment: how would I take my `card_info.html` and feed it 5 different `%s and %i` values in this case? – so it'd look like `<p id="pay-card">
    <img id="pay-box-img" src="{% static 'img/payment-card.png' %}" height="14">
    <span id="card-number">%s x-%i %s</span>
</p>` 5 different times with all different values

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you get your card number from a Django model called "Payment". The card number is stored in the model's `card_number` field. In your view:

```
from django.views import generic
from myapp.models import Payment
import re

class PaymentView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Payment
    template_name = 'payments/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PaymentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        card_number = self.object.card_number
        # leave only last digits after final dash
        context['card_number'] = re.sub(r'^.*-(\d+)$', r'xxxx-\1', card_number)
        return context
```

In your template `payments/detail.html` you can now simply show the card number:

```
{% load static %}
<div class="bottom-box" id="left">
    <span id="title">Banks and cards</span>
    <p id="pay-card">
        <img id="pay-box-img" src="{% static 'img/payment-card.png' %}" height="14">
        <span id="card-number">{{ card_number }}</span>
    </p>        
</div>
```

Hook up the view to an url:

```
# app/urls.py
from .views import PaymentView
urlpatterns = [
    url('^payments/(?<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PaymentView.as_view(), name='payment_view'),
]
```